# SharePoint 2016 for 5000 users and 30 Tera byte data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sql-server, 2016, windows-server

I have a requirement to create a SharePoint 2016 plan for 5000 users and 30 TB data to be used, I need help with the approach for design and deployment. How many Windows servers and SQL servers would I need and how do i go about with the licencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not easy to give you exact answer, i would consider following things to design an environment

- How many concurrent user will use it.
- Do you need High Availability? then you need each server in pair expect Distributed Cache( no HA) and Workflow Manager( which is either 1 server or 3).
- you need dedicated servers for search service as you have 30TB of data which will be huge.
- Are you plan for Office Online Server?

I would go with

- 2 WFE
- 2 Application server with Distributed Cache role
- SQL Server with Always-ON, again number of servers depend upon the storage limitation.
- 2 Query and 2 Crawl Server ( you can change it)
- If using the OOS then a dedicate server for it.

SharePoint Server 2016 is required for each running instance of the software, and CALs are required for each person or device accessing a SharePoint Server.

https://products.office.com/en-us/SharePoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview

.
You can also think about the SharePoint Online ( Office 365) where you dont need to worry about the servers. You have to pay per user that's it, rest Microsoft will take care of back-end.
What you have to do, just check the following Limitation and Boundaries.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8F34FF47-B749-408B-ABC0-B605E1F6D498?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47521/discussion-on-answer-by-waqas-sarwar-mcse-sharepoint-2016-for-5000-users-and-30).